# Set standard number format with thousand separator, 2 decimals and minus sign for negative numbers using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I've seen the question asked before on stackoverflow, how to get normal number format with thousand separator and 2 decimals. The answer was to set:

```
    rng.NumberFormat = "##0.00"
```

But this is incomplete, because, at least on my computer, I don't get any space separator between millions and thousands. So I have changed that to:

```
    rng.NumberFormat = "### ### ##0.00"
```

But this is again incomplete, because for some reason negative numbers were formatted to look like they have a space between the minus sign and the number. See below:

```
- 12.4
```

So, there are some things left to do to arrive at Excels "built-in" "format as number" formats. Additionally the formatting that I apply though VBA is described as Custom by Excel.

Is there any way to set the format to be the standard built in format as number with thousand separators, 2 decimals and minus signs for negative numbers?

I'm looking for something like:

```
    rng.NumberFormat = "Number, 2, minus"
```

Comment: Have you tried simply `#,##0.00`, assuming your regional settings use a space as the thousands separator?

Comment: There is no point in putting multiple `#` in a sequence i.e. `#,##0.00` => `#,#0.00` and `##0.00` => `#0.00` should be the same format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rng.NumberFormat = "# ##0.00:-# ##0.00"
```

You put the format for positive numbers before : and the format for negative after. You don't need to put hundreds of # signs in the format, just enough to show what the 1000's separator is.

Comment: How can I make it not to  display zeros after the point if the number is whole number. For example 1000 instead of 1000.00 , but if there is numbers after the decimal point they should be displayed like 1000.22

Comment: You either have decimals or you don't. Buy you could conditionally change the NumberFormat if the value is an integer/long.

Answer (score -1):

So, this is an old post. But people may still have this problem, and **I have a workaround**. This solution works nicely for *contained* data sets, such as a table or a chart you want thousand separator for.

The issue is (at least how it is for me, in continental Europe) that the system thousand separator is " ", i.e a space. Hence, the number format for thousand separator ought to be "# ###" or equivalently "# ##0" (or "# ##0,00" if you want 2 decimals with comma as decimal separator). Indeed, if you make a chart and ask Excel to format axis as numbers with thousand separator, Excel gives you this number format: "# ##0".

However, if you use "# ##0" or "# ###" to make your own number format, Excel *only* gives you a separator between million and thousand. E.g. if your numbers are a billion and ten thousand, the chart axis will show 1000000 000 and 10 000. Excel will *not* give you the desired 1 000 000 000 and 10 000.

Note: The issue is of course the same if you want to use other thousand separators than space, say, comma or punctuation.

This is my solution to this problem for the case without decimals (just add the number of decimals you want like you normally would):

```
Dim n As Long, i As Long, MyFormat As String, MySeparator as String, MyData As Range, x as double

Set MyData = 'Range containing your data
MySeparator = 'Your prefered thousand separator

'Number of separators you need for the largest ABS-value in your dataset
x=Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(MyData) 'Largest number
x=Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(x,-Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(MyData)) 'Largest ABS-value
n = Int((Len(CStr(Int(x))) - 1) / 3) 'Number of separators required

MyFormat = "###" 'Initial value

For i = 1 To n
   MyFormat = "###" & MySeparator & MyFormat
Next
```

Comment: How does this deal with negative numbers? OP says *But this is again incomplete, because for some reason negative numbers were formatted to look like they have a space between the minus sign and the number*

Comment: Yes. The construction of the x variable ensures formating of negative numbers is dealt with.

Comment: This answer contains a fundamental misunderstanding of the meaning of the characters in a format string. In a format string, the `,` character means *current system thousands separator*. It will be substituted with the current system thousands separator. A space, on the other hand, does not have this special meaning in the format string. Thus, on a system where the space is the thousands separator, `format(21345123, "#,###.00")` will produce `21 345 123,00`. Note how a comma is used in the format string, but a space appears in the result, and note how that space is repeated for millions etc.